# Firebase admin looking for a different default project than the one I'm currently working on my local environment

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm building this cloud function in my local environment and I need to save something to Firestore:

Here's how I'm initializing the `firebase-admin` app:

**myFunction.js**

```
if (!adminHasInitialized) {
  console.log("INITIALIZING ADMIN APP");                    // THIS IS BEING LOGGED
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  });
  adminHasInitialized = true;
}
```

And here's how I'm trying to update my Firestore:

```
await admin.firestore().collection("myCollection").doc("myDoc").update({
  ...
});
```

**NOTE:** I'm working on `MY_PROJECT_1`

And this is the error I'm getting:

> details: 'No document to update: projects/**MY_PROJECT_2**/databases/(default)/documents/myCollection/myDoc',

**PROBLEM**

Somehow `firebase-admin` is looking inside another database for a different project **MY_PROJECT_2** that I have.

When I run: `firebase projects:list`, this is what I get:

```
Project Display Name   │ Project ID                  │ Resource Location ID
MY_PROJECT_1           │ MY_PROJECT_1 (current)      │ us-central1
MY_PROJECT_2           │ MY_PROJECT_2                │ us-central1
```

So the current project is correct.

Also I have this file, which I set the default as **MY_PROJECT_1**

**.firebaserc**

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "MY_PROJECT_1"
  }
}
```

I also tried to add the DB URL when I'm initializing the app, as:

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL: "https://MY_PROJECT_1.firebaseio.com"
});
```

But I keep getting the same error.

**NOTE:** I'm running this function in my local environment using `babel-node` throught the following command:

`npx babel-node functions/src/myFunction.js`

---

**QUESTION**

How is `firebase-admin` getting a different default project than the one I'm currently working on?

---

**UPDATE 1**

I think that `firebase-admin` is getting the default configuration from the `gcloud` SDK that is installed in my PC.

From:

> [C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\configurations\config_default]

**config_default:**

```
[core]
account = my@email.com
project = MY_PROJECT_2     // MAYBE IT IS COMING FROM HERE
```

**UPDATE 2**

So far, the only thing I've managed to make it work is with:

```
admin.initializeApp({
  projectId: "MY_PROJECT_1",
  databaseURL: "https://MY_PROJECT_1.firebaseio.com"
});
```

This gives me the correct project when I run this function locally.

Answer (score 2):

Since version 1.0.0 of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions you don't need anymore to initialize with `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);`, see the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#new_initialization_syntax_for_firebase-admin), which explains that:

> `firebase-admin` is now initialized without any parameters within the
>   Cloud Functions runtime.

So please try with:

```
if (!adminHasInitialized) {
  console.log("INITIALIZING ADMIN APP");                   
  admin.initializeApp();
  adminHasInitialized = true;
}
```

Comment: Hi Renaud! Thanks for your help. But I'm not initializing it with `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);`. I'm just passing the [AppOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin#initializeapp) object. When I do `admin.initializeApp();` I still get the other project. I think somehow `firebase-admin` is getting the default project from the `gcloud` SDK that I have currently installed.

Comment: Hello, you should try with `JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);` after configuring the values in your Firebase project, see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#functionsconfigfirebase_removed)